# Replacing a character with another - always the 3rd last character postion from the right - how to do that?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have an invoice number.
I would like to replace the 3rd last character with a dot (.)

Example:

```
XA260153758i01
```

I would like to replace the small `i` with dot (.):

```
XA260153758.01
```

Now, the small `i` could be anything, So I do not know what character will be in the 3rd last postion, I only know that the 3rd last character should always be replaced with a dot (.)

How to script that ?

Comment: None of the answers to the duplicate question are actually optimal if you're replacing a *single* character. Cid's answer below would be more suitable.

Comment: Or you can do it in a one-liner like this (assuming your string is called `s`): `s = new string(s.Select((c, i) => i == s.Length - 3 ? '.' : c).ToArray());`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1), it's pretty nice to manipulate strings easily :

```
// using System.Text;

var input = new StringBuilder("XA260153758i01");
    
// TODO : Check for the length to avoid ArgumentOutOfRangeException (negative indexes)
input[input.Length - 3] = '.';
    
Console.WriteLine(input.ToString()); // output is XA260153758.01
```

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. I am new to the forum.
Cid's answer works perfectly. Thank you.